# Is there a way to make the current active application stand out on OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I've just switched to a double-display configuration, and I still make mistakes regarding which is the current active (focused) application. Is there a way to get the active window to be highlighted?

(Or for example, have the other windows automatically turn transparent?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide all other applications, or <kbd>Opt</kbd>-click an application's Dock icon to hide all others.

---

[Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/) allows to dim and/or blur background applications, as well as several other effects.

[image: Dimming]

[image: Mosaic effect]

Comment: Isolator is awsome, just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> (unless configured for something else) to make the current application's windows stand out, in an Exposé like manner. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> needs to be pressed if you don't have access to F-keys enabled by default.

See under *System Preferences » Exposé and Spaces*:

[image]

Here's the effect for one application window:

[image]